# Sources (Tutorials, HowTos, etc.) for IBurg, Burg

Tags: linux, compiler-construction

I'm working on a little compiler project. A prof. told me that burg or iburg is a good starting point.

Next semester I have to use it in the compiler construction course anyway so I thought it's good when I start with iburg. But: There aren't any tutorials on how to start.

Where do I find good sources beside the linked paper in the readme of the zip file on http://code.google.com/p/iburg/ ?

Comment: Have you looked at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to find a copy of A [Retargetable C Compiler: Design and Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805316701) by Fraser and Hanson. The book discusses lburg (a variant of iburg) in some detail with examples for x86, SPARC, and MIPS.

Comment: Note that this is the same Fraser and Hanson who authored the paper you mentioned finding at http://code.google.com/p/iburg/.

Comment: +1 for the Link but I'm searching for online tutorials which help me getting started quick.